# What is the correct and secure scenario of repetitive async stripe payments?

Tags: stripe-payments, payment, credit-card, card

This is the task:
A User should add a card using an app to their account. After completing some service(taxi service) card should be automatically charged. So the question is:

1. Who should store card credentials? (backend or App)
2. In what form card should be stored?